# Can someone explain to me why this topology is (strictly?)coarser than Left Hand Topology?

Tags: general-topology

Is T strictly coarser than L? I'll provide my proof that RR is coarser than L and if someone could explain to me or let me know of a correct proof, that'd be great.

Let T = { V $\subset$ R $\vert$ if x $\in$ V, then there exists a $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ such that x $\in$ [a , $\infty$) $\subset$ V}

L = { U $\subset$ R $\vert$ if x $\in$ U, then there exists a,b $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ such that x $\in$ [a, b) $\subset$ U}

Claim. T $\subset$ L (proper subset of)

Proof. Let V $\in$ T and let x $\in$ V. Then there exists a $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ such that x $\in$ [a, $\infty$) $\subset$ V. Then x $\in$ [a, x + 1) $\subset$ [a, $\infty$) $\subset$ V $\subset$ U $\in$ L, where a, x + 1 $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$. Then V $\in$ L.

Claim. L $\not$$\subset$ T (This is where I'm getting confused.)

Proof. Let U $\in$ L and x $\in$ U such that there exists a, b $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$, x $\in$ [a, b) $\subset$ U.

Why can't x $\in$ [a, b) $\subset$ [a, $\infty$) since if x is in an interval of real numbers a, b, can't it be in the interval of a to infinity. Like, if x$\in$[a,b), then x $\in$ [x, b) $\subset$ [x, $\infty$) $\subset$ V $\in$ T, where x $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$. I know that I say, let V$_{1}$ = [0, $\infty$) and say x = 1, then 1 $\not$$\in$ [0,1), would that be enough-- or can someone shed some light for me.

Also, from the book I'm studying from, it says the RR (Right Ray) is coarser than U (Usual Topology). I can see that an element of RR is an element of U, but I'm trying to find out why an element of U is not an element of RR, would it be like the counter example where if x = 1, then U$_{1}$=(0,2), then 1 $\not$$\in$ (2, $\infty$) . If someone could give me a concrete example I can understand, that'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set $[0,1)$. Since $[0,1)\in L$ and $[0,1)\notin T$, $L\not\subset T$. We know that $[0,1)\notin T$ because otherwise $[0,1)$ would have to contain a set of the type $[a,+\infty)$.

Concerning the other question, you should post it as another question, explaining what the right ray topology is.

Comment: So to speak very roughly about it, if I can't fit the form of the second topology into an element of the first topology, then the second topology cannot be coarser than the first topology? As well as to say if I can fit the form of topology A inside another topology B element, then A is finer than B? Oh and thank you again for responding.

Comment: The topology $T$ is strictly coarser than the topology $L$ because $T\subset L$ and $L\not\subset T$.